# Open new window with input url Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to make an extension for chrome to open the page with crafted url .
The extension only need user to copy paste the string number and press button and it will instant open the new window with prepared url + inputted string number . The code is below

The problem i have right now is `number` always return `null` and the url will lead to 404 page .  I would appreciate it if anyone can point out why it return null and how to fix it since im new to this JavaScript

```js
function number() {
  var number = document.querySelector("code");
  chrome.windows.create({
    url: "https://gamecrackzome.gg/game/" + number,
    focused: true,
    state: "maximized",
  });

}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var button = document.getElementById("go");
  button.onclick = number;
});

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
<style>
</style>

</head>
<body>
    </br>
    <input type="text" id="code">
    </br>
    <input type="submit" id="go" value="GO">
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `document.querySelector("#code").value` or `document.getElementById("code").value`

Comment: Voting to close as _Not reproducible or was caused by a typo
While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers._

Comment: `querySelector` needs a CSS like selector: `document.querySelector("#code").value`. Also add `.value` to get the value

Comment: I think you meant: `document.querySelector('#code').value`  Just searching for "code" is looking for an element like `<code>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems.

1. `querySelector("code")` selects the first `<code>` element (it is returning `null` because you don't have any). To select an element by its ID you need to use an [ID selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#id-selectors): `querySelector("#code")`.
2. An element is not the value typed into it. For that you need [the `value` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement#Properties): `querySelector("#code").value`